# Numerate tree nodes from linked list

Tags: php, algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

I have the tree nodes connection info in the form of the linked list and ID of the root node. I need to numerate this nodes in such order that any lower level node in result should have higher number than any node of a higher level. Numbering starts from the ID value of the root node and incrementing by 1 for every other node. Order of the nodes on the same level is not important. What algorithms and data structures I may use to solve this problem before I start reinventing the wheel and to avoid the pitfalls? Language that will be used is pure PHP and the data comes from MySQL DB, but any solution like pseudo-code or just plain explanations is welcomed.

Edit:
So far I came up to this (thanks Beta for helping me out):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(551285, 551286),
    array(551286, 551290),
    array(551286, 551297),
    array(551288, 551432),
    array(551289, 552149),
    array(551290, 551292),
    array(551292, 551294),
    array(551296, 551355),
    array(551296, 552245),
    array(551297, 551299),
    array(551299, 551301),
    array(551299, 551304),
    array(551304, 551306),
    array(551306, 551307),
    array(551307, 551308),
    array(551308, 551309),
    array(551309, 551312),
    array(551311, 551328),
    array(551312, 551313),
    array(551313, 551315),
    array(551315, 551316),
    array(551316, 551317),
    array(551286, 551288),
    array(551286, 551289),
    array(551286, 551320),
    array(551290, 551322),
    array(551292, 551324),
    array(551294, 551296),
    array(551294, 551326),
    array(551297, 551342),
    array(551299, 551344),
    array(551301, 551303),
    array(551304, 551346),
    array(551307, 551349),
    array(551309, 551311),
    array(551309, 551353),
    array(551313, 551357),
    array(551317, 552094),
    array(551286, 551287),
    array(551290, 551291),
    array(551292, 551293),
    array(551294, 551295),
    array(551297, 551298),
    array(551299, 551300),
    array(551301, 551302),
    array(551304, 551305),
    array(551309, 551310),
    array(551313, 551314)
);

var_dump(numerateTreeNodes($data, 551285));

function numerateTreeNodes($linked_nodes, $root_node)
{
    $numbered_nodes = array();
    $queue = new SplQueue();
    $queue->enqueue($root_node);
    $counter = $root_node;
    $children_grouped = groupDirectChildren($linked_nodes);

    while ($queue->count()) {
        $t = $queue->dequeue();
        $numbered_nodes[$counter++] = $t;
        if (isset($children_grouped[$t])) {
            foreach ($children_grouped[$t] as $t_child) {
                $queue->enqueue($t_child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $numbered_nodes;
}

function groupDirectChildren($nodes)
{
    $grouped = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $n) {
        $grouped[$n[0]][] = $n[1];
    }
    return $grouped;
}
```

Any suggestions/corrections?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a Breadth-First Search?

Comment: No, I'm not. Are you suggesting this algorithm as a solution?

Comment: Thanks, now I'm looked BFS and DFS on Wikipedia and have to ask which is better in my case (full tree traverse, right?)

Comment: BFS is better. First assign a number to the root node. Then iterate over all the nodes it points to. Then iterate over all the nodes *they* point to. Then all the nodes *they* point to, and so on until there are no unmarked nodes left.

Comment: You probably want to take a second look at how DFS works if you're not sure if it works for your case.

BTW, this is a list of links for sure, but doesn't quite look like a linked list to me.

Comment: Also, take a look at this for a (efficient?) queue implementation in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php

Comment: Sorry for the multi-post but you probably want to store (once for all) the children (in an array, hashtable or something?) in order to be efficient (linear time if you do not iterate over every edge at each step?).

Comment: @user189, sorry I didn't mean linked list in it's true definition. Is here a need to use true queue implementation? And I didn't quite understand how I can store children once to not iterate over every edge. Also please check edited version, I added unset for used pairs to reduce array length for every function call.

Comment: It depends. If you use array_shift you will probably lose un time. If you don't you will probably lose in memory. You decide if you want to implement or use a queue, but be aware that your algorithm will be slow if you have to shift everything at each step.

With PHP, you can easily store the children in an array with arbitrary keys, right?

Comment: @user189, please check edited version.

Comment: Seems OK to me, if you know it's a tree.

For further comments, you might want to post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/